# WIF and Authorization based on logic besides roles (also to disable buttons)

Tags: .net, authorization, wif, claims-based-identity, abac

We have a *Asp.Net-Web-Api* server side and wpf (*Desktop*) client side.

Would a *WIF* (*Windows Identity Foundation*) solution fit when:

- we need not only to block access to *web-api*, but also to pass authorization rights information to the client side in order to disable buttons?
- *authorization* is based not only on roles. Authorization rights are different according to the *type of action*, and the *type of object* to which an action might be applied? For example, an *action* could be "attach_document" and an *object* could be say "Project". Or "edit_subentities" for a certain instance of a "SuperEntity"...?
- also *authorization* would be based on **logic** applied to both *User Attributes* and *Object Properties*. To clarify, we have a tree structure of *Organizations*. A *User* belongs to certain *Organization*, and an *Object* should be related to a certain *Organization*. **For only some Roles**, the rights are dictated by the fact, **whether the *Object's Organization* is a subordinate of the Authenticated User's Organization or not**. ...?

Secondarily (not sure if it is correct to ask),

- If *WIF* fits, it would helpful to know any keywords for googling on how to get started on solution implementation for the **logic** part
- Are there some better alternatives?

Sorry if the question is too wide or something is not clear or incorrect. It would be helpful to know that the *WIF* solution is not the best choise in our case before spending time on experimenting. Tanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ABAC ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)), the attribute-based access control model. It is an updated model which, instead of just looking at roles (RBAC), looks at attributes of:

- the user e.g. role, department, clearance...
- the resource e.g. classification and other attributes
- the action e.g. view, delete, approve
- the context / environment e.g. time of the day, IP address...

ABAC's model provides

- externalized authorization (just like claims-based authorization and RBAC)
- centralized authorization: the authorization logic is maintained in a central component
- policy-based: the authorization logic is expressed as policies that bind together the attributes.

Example:

- A user can view a document if the document's department == the user's department AND the document status == PUBLISHED.

In particular, have a look at XACML ([xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml)). XACML provides an externalized policy-based authorization solution that you can apply to your .NET applications.

[image: XACML Architecture]

**EDIT** by question asker (taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML)):

- **PAP** - Policy Administration Point - Point which manages access authorization policies
- **PDP** - Policy Decision Point - Point which evaluates access requests against authorization policies before issuing access decisions
- **PEP** - Policy Enforcement Point - Point which intercepts user's access request to a resource, makes a decision request to the PDP to obtain the access decision (i.e. access to the resource is approved or rejected), and acts on the received decision
- **PIP** - Policy Information Point - The system entity that acts as a source of attribute values (i.e. a resource, subject, environment)
- **(PRP)** - Policy Retrieval Point - Point where the XACML access authorization policies are stored, typically a database or the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We are going to try it. We started building our own simple implementation based on the concepts presented in `ABAC` and `XACML` (in conjunction with `Claims`). But are there already some good simple open source _.Net_ implementations?

Answer (score 0):

At the very first approach and thanks to [Dominick Baier](http://leastprivilege.com/about/)'s contribution, i've come up with a custom `ClaimsAuthorizationManager`. Seems that it is possible to use WIF as the solution.

- Still don't know whether WIF fits best.
- There's also a question if it is ok to share the authorization logic between client and server side. Haven't thought about that yet.

There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326584/claims-authorization-for-specific-resources) post about similar problem.

---

The very first thing, i've come up to is to check access like this:

```
authorizationManager.CheckAccess("show_subresources", "resource_org_id", "20d55788-bf46-43f0-b6c5-ccb6be687b90");
```

I'm checking the access imperatively. As for declarative approach with attribute [`ClaimsPrincipalPermission(....)`] above the method, this seems not to work in our case, because the resource_organization_id is not known until the resource is obtained. The very first approach version of the manager looks like this:

```
public class AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{
    public const string ActionType = "http://application/claims/authorization/action";
    public const string ResourceType = "http://application/claims/authorization/resource";

    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        //logic

        return false;
    }

    public bool CheckAccess(string action, params string[] resources)
    {
        var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;

        var context = CreateAuthorizationContext(
            principal,
            action,
            resources
            );

        return CheckAccess(context);
    }

    private AuthorizationContext CreateAuthorizationContext(ClaimsPrincipal principal, string action, params string[] resources)
    {
        var actionClaims = new Collection<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ActionType, action)
        };

        var resourceClaims = new Collection<Claim>();

        if (resources != null && resources.Length > 0)
        {
            resources.ToList().ForEach(ar => resourceClaims.Add(new Claim(ResourceType, ar)));
        }

        return new AuthorizationContext(
            principal,
            resourceClaims,
            actionClaims);
    }
}
```

Note that i'm using the `Microsoft.IdentityModel` *nuget package* for .Net 4.0.

The manager should be actualized via the app.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="microsoft.identityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <configSections>

    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

    <system.identityModel>
        <identityConfiguration>
            <claimsAuthorizationManager type="ClaimsAuthorizationJustATry.AuthorizationManager, ClaimsAuthorizationJustATry"/>
        </identityConfiguration>
    </system.identityModel>
</configuration>
```

But i did it like this:

```
FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfiguration.ClaimsAuthorizationManager = new AuthorizationManager();
```